# Adding distinct data to jComboBox from database

Tags: java, sql

I have a jComboBox which i want to fill up with the departments of the students in a database. Now the same department occurs many times in the table so i want each department name to go only once to the list of items. The present code i wrote is not giving the desired result. It puts the same department name multiple times on the ComboBox list. How can i solve this?
My code to fetch department names is given below:

```
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydaatabase1","root","Password123");
            String sql1 = "select distinct (dept) from droptest";
            PreparedStatement pss = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ResultSet rs = pss.executeQuery(sql1);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String d = rs.getString("dept");
                jComboBox1.addItem(d);
            }
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is correct. There is no need of any group statement since you are only performing distinct on only 1 column. There might be an issue in the while statement which adds item.

Comment: I have put the above code in the Constructor so i am guessing it is being called more than once somehow. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you need use group by in select data...

> select columnName
>    from tablename
>   Group by columnName

```
    Select dept 
    From droptest
    Group by dept
```

Group by is like distinct

Comment: Group by is not required. He is only taking a distinct on 1 column.

Comment: Working well both of them